# Tkinter unable to get updated a StringVar

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I am reading serial info and want to pass it to the GUI in Tkinter .
This code is working, but when I want to use canvas(because I will do a dashboard type GUI), I do not get any print out on the GUI.

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    pass

import serial
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.font as tkf

ser = serial.Serial('COM2')
ser.baudrate = 9600

def update():
    c = StringVar()
    c=ser.readline()
    theta.set(c)  
    root.after(100,update)

root=Tk()
root.title("viento")
theta = StringVar()

w = Label(root, textvariable = theta, font ="Times 16 bold", fg="red")
w.pack()

root.after(100,update)    
root.mainloop()
```

As soon as I change the label statement with

```
w=Canvas(root,width = 200, height= 100)
w.pack()
w.create_text(100,50,text=theta.get())
```

I get an empty GUI . What is wrong ?

Comment: You only `create_text` **once**, when the program starts (at which point `theta.get() == ''`). Also, starting a script with `if __name__ = '__main__': pass` is *really weird*.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, you can not use a `StringVar` for setting the text displayed on a Canvas. You can, however, get the ID of the text created on the canvas and [re-configure it afterwards](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/canvas-methods.html).

Something like this:

```
def update():
    w.itemconfigure(text_id, text=ser.readline())
    root.after(100, update)

w = Canvas(root, width=200, height=100)
w.pack()
text_id = w.create_text(100, 50, text="")
```

Answer (score 0):

thanks for your help.
Jonrsharpe were right.Create text executed just once, so combing that comment with Tobias, moved that statement w.create_text(100,50,text=theta.get()) to the update function and then I got what I was expecting. The only minor comment is that the values were overwritten one over the following.Not sure why . It seems like the new updated value did not clear the previous one and in the GUI after a few samples the values were impossible to read.
For me really minor, since I was able to fix the problem and designed my Canvas GUI ,that is now up and running .

Comment: Well, that's because you are _creating_ a new text, as subtly hinted by the method name `create_text`. If you want to _update_ the existing text, you have to get the ID of the existing text and reconfigure it to show a different string, as I suggested in my answer.